# How to implement mobile split screen, but with a width of double the screen size?

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design

I'd like to create a "split screen" mobile website, but with the ability to scroll left and right. I think this image sums it up well:

[Here's an image I sketched about the result I want.](https://i.ibb.co/gZD4B7t/whatiwant.jpg)

I tried it several ways using CSS, but it always failed somehow. The `width: 200%` made it much more than the double of the screen width, viewports always fixed the size to the screen. I suppose, it shouldn't be so hard. Do you have any ideas to make this happen? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

try using `width: 200vw;`
this might solve your problem

this example might help you understand

```css
.inner {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200vw;
}
.outer {
  overflow-x: auto;
}
span {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #00ff00;
  width: 50%;
}
p {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #ff00ff;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <span>
      hello
    </span>
    <p>hello there</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! However, [this](https://i.ibb.co/x221w9B/IMG-20190110-132037.jpg) happens. Here's my code:

`html, body {
 width:200vw;
 height: 100%;
        color: #000000;
}

.leftContent{
    width: 50%;
    height: 100vh;
    float: left;
    background: #00babc;
}
.rightContent{
    width: 50%;
    height: 100vh;
    float: right;
    color: #ffffff;
    background: #003f70;
}`

Both width and height fails somehow.

Comment: try using it on direct div, rather than body.
and you shouldn't apply any CSS on HTML tag, thats not a good practice

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will keep that in mind. I made a contentWrapper div instead of using it on body, and the same happens :(

Comment: try giving it display: inline-block;
If possible try sharing some more code, its hard predicting and guessing where its going wrong.

Comment: [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/bzkdq8rf/) is literally my whole code. Works on desktop, but fails on smartphone.

Comment: Added `<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' />` and it solved my problem! Thank you for your time :)

Comment: <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">